# Ajax function not being called on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I am a beginner in this so excuse me if I'm just dumb.

So basically I'm trying to get a div to reload with information from a php file after submitting a form using ajax and this is what I have.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#searchForm').submit(function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'result.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
    data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      $('#underInput').html(response);
     },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
 });
 });
</script>

    <form class="form-group" id="searchForm" onsubmit="return false">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="search" class="form-control" name="user" type="text" placeholder="Enter instagram username">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit">Sök</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
        <div id="underInput"/>
```

result.php

```
//dont want to show calculation for therate here
echo '<h2><?php echo $_POST["user"]?> can charge <?php echo $therate?>€ per 
post</h2>';
```

Nothing happens when i click submit, why?

Comment: remove onsubmit="return false" in form tag

Comment: why did you have this attribute onsubmit="return false"

Comment: your code is working...check console you are getting any error?

Comment: Did you include jQuery library into your code?

Comment: Nothing is happening because you have written " onsubmit="return false" "   . remove that

Comment: Nothing happens even when I remove that. The div is still empty and the console shows nothing.

Comment: If I remove the 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> I do get an error in the console though. Which means the code is running right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on click instead of submit

**Example-**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on("click", function(event){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'result.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
        data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          $('#underInput').html(response);
         },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
     });
     });
});
```

Then replace your php code with this code

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$_POST["user"].' can charge '.$therate.' € per 
post</h2>'; 
?>
```

Comment: ugh, still nothing happens :/. I have also included this in the <head> tag: 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Is there something else I must add?

Comment: try to alert something if its alert then tell me example $('#submit').on("click", function(event){
alert("hello");

});

Comment: Not even if I use $('#searchForm').submit(function(event). Not getting any alert nor a message in the console.

Comment: ok see my updated answer . i added document ready code update it into your code and check .

Comment: Yeah if i add an alert before $('#underInput').html(response);. It does show up. But the div still does not change.

Comment: did you try to alert response ? what response is comming

Comment: Not really sure what that means. Now the div does update. But only for like half a second or so. Then it resets back to being empty.

Comment: div data updated correctly ? and div how to blank automatically without page refresh. icheck any code make it blank or not

Comment: Got it! The other guys told me to remove onsubmit="return false". When i put it back it worked with your solution! Thanks!